# Close dialog when algorithm is finished (QGIS plugin)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I've read many threads on this but I'm not able to figure out the solution (I'm a beginner to the plugin creation...).

What I what to do is to close the dialog window when the algorithm has finished its job.

That's the piece of code of the `alg.dialog.py`:

```
    class CreateModelDialog(QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
        def __init__(self, iface):
            QDialog.__init__(self)
            self.iface = iface
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
            self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(self.createModel)

            self.manageGui()

........

    def createModel(self):
        modelName = self.bxDBname.text()
        modelType = self.cmbBxModelType.currentText()
        lengthString = self.cmbBxLengthUnit.currentText()
        timeString = self.cmbBxTimeUnit.currentText()
        workingDir = self.OutFilePath
        print 'Direttori recuperata ..... ' , workingDir
        isChild = 1.0
        createModel(modelName, workingDir, modelType, isChild, lengthString, timeString)
```

So `self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(self.createModel)`, when clicked runs the `createModel` method.

But the dialog remains opended, where should I edit the code?

---

This is the `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.iface = iface
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
    self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(self.createModel)

    self.manageGui()
```

---

This is the function in the main `plugin.py` file:

```
def runCreateModel(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
    self.dlgMD = mdDialog.CreateModelDialog(self.iface)
    # show the dialog
    self.dlgMD.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    self.dlgMD.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `__init__` function in plugin implementation find a line where your dialog was created.

Probably it will be:

```
self.dlg = CreateModelDialog()
```

Then if you want to close dialog window you have to execute:

```
self.dlg.close()
```

Put this line into the function with your algorithm at the end of code.

Example structure of your plugin.py:

```
class CreateModel:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        ...
        self.dlg = CreateModelDialog()
        ...
        # connections
        self.dlg.button.clicked.connect(self.function)

    def function(self):
        # some code for your algorithm
        self.dlg.close()

    ...
    def run(self):
        ...
```

Comment: mm.. nope.. I don't have any ``self.dlg = CreateModelDialog()`` in the __init__ function. I edited the question adding the ``__init__`` function..

Comment: Have you used plugin builder?

Comment: Yes.. The plugis is quite complicated with many dialogs.. but we started it with the plugin builder

Comment: So you have got there two .py files among the others: `pluginname_dialog.py` and `pluginname.py`. Check out the second file. There should be an implementation class (CreateModel I guess...).

Comment: Yep.. So, I looked into the ``plugin.py`` and I found the functions that call the dialogs (I have many of them in the plugin).. See EDIT2 (sorry for being so bothering..).. I tried to add ``self.dlgMD.close()`` but is doesn't work...

Comment: Ok, then in plugin.py in this class you can create a function with your algorithm, then connect to the button or something. In this function at the end of the code put `self.dlgMD.close()`. Now if you open your plugin and click this button, function will be executed and after that dialog will be closed. It works for me in my plugins. I will edit my first post with an example schema.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27388/discussion-between-matteo-and-dmh126).